# Passing information using segues programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I've got this class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var keywords = []

    ...

}
```

and another class:

```
class ExplorerViewController: UIViewController {

    func searchMapSegue() {
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewController") as! ViewController
        next.keywords = searchKeywordsArray
        self.presentViewController(next, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and searchMapSegue() is being called at the click of a button.

and I'm attempting to pass the searchKeywordsArray to the ViewController but I'm getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Can someone tell me what the issue is here? I am not using storyboard.

Comment: In code you are using storyboard and in description you are saying "I am not using storyboard." what does it mean?

Comment: @NiravD Oh sorry I meant I'm not using the main.storyboard. I simply followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813942/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-viewcontroller-and-pass-data.

Comment: Are you working with XIb?

Comment: @NiravD I'm not at the moment. Should I be?

Comment: Are you generating design programmatically?

Comment: @NiravD Everything up to now has been generated programmatically yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123544/discussion-between-tryingtolearn-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you need to consider here.

1) Your current viewcontroller and ExplorerViewController are in same storyborad? if yes than you can use self.storyboard. if not you can't use self.storyboard.

You need to use below code

```
let explorerViewController =  UIStoryboard(name: NAME_OF_YOUR_STORYBOARD, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExplorerViewController") as! ExplorerViewController
```

2) are you setting identifier properly? You need to set identifier. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Hope this will solve your problem